# How to convert string without quotes to dictionary in python

Tags: python, string, dictionary, tensorflow

I have to convert string without quotes into dictionary.

```
device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 8GB, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0
```

the 'device', 'name' and 'pci bus id' have to be keys,

and '0', 'GeForce GTX 1080 8GB', '0000:01:00.0' have to be values.

I get this from tensorflow.python.client.list_local_devices()

Comment: change their type to string maybe?

Comment: They make strings without quotes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using, two `.split()`'s and *dictionary comprehension*, first `.split(', ')` divides up the entire string, the second `split(': ')` divides up the items of list to be cast as `keys and values`

```
s = "device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 8GB, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0"
d = {i.split(': ')[0]: i.split(': ')[1] for i in s.split(', ')}
```

> ```
> {'device': '0', 'name': 'GeForce GTX 1080 8GB', 'pci bus id': '0000:01:00.0'}
> ```

Comment: That fails when you have as values arrays

Answer (score 4):

First, you have to split the string by ', ' (comma and space) to separate each key : value in your string. After, for each string with 'key: value' you must split it for ': ' (colon and space) to get key and value separately to build your dictionary.

```
    dict = {}
    s = "device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 8GB, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0"

    '''split to separate the main string in 'key: value' substrings'''
    key_value = s.split(", ")

'''each substring is separated in key and value to be appended into dictionary'''

    for v in key_value:
       aux = v.split(": ")
       dict[aux[0]] = aux[1]

    print(dict)
```

The outuput:

```
{'name': 'GeForce GTX 1080 8GB', 'device': '0', 'pci bus id': '0000:01:00.0'}
```

Comment: nice catch on the trailing spaces when splitting

Comment: How can I do if I have something like '{source: s3, prefixFiles: [Tracking_Sent, Tracking_Bounces, Tracking_Opens, Tracking_Clicks, Tracking_SendJobs]')

Comment: @Eduardo Soares

I give you a cookie for the nice response.