# How to convert string without quotes and with arrays and sub-dictionary to a dictionary in python?

Tags: python

I had the next string without quotes and with arrays and sub-dictionaries:

```
s ='{source: [s3, kinesis], aws_access_key_id: {myaws1, myaws2}, aws_secret_access_key: REDACTED_POSSIBLE_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, bucketName: bucket, region_name: eu-west-1, fileType: zip, typeIngestion: FULL, project: trackingcampaigns, functionalArea: client, filePaths: [s3Sensor/2018/], prefixFiles: [Tracking_Sent, Tracking_Bounces, Tracking_Opens, Tracking_Clicks, Tracking_SendJobs], prefixToTables: {Tracking_Bounces: MNG_TRACKING_EXTRACT_BOUNCES_3, Tracking_Sent: MNG_TRACKING_EXTRACT_SENT_3, Tracking_Clicks: MNG_TRACKING_EXTRACT_CLICKS_3, Tracking_Opens: MNG_TRACKING_EXTRACT_OPENS_3, Tracking_SendJobs: MNG_TRACKING_EXTRACT_SENDJOBS_3}, stagingPath: /zipFiles/}'
```

I would like to convert it to a dictionary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a String representation of a Dictionary to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary)

Comment: @Ahndwoo it is not duplicate in my case is without quotes

Comment: in order to evaluate the string you need quotes on keys and string values. You will need to parse the string using separators as `,` and `: ` to parse your string into a dictionary

Comment: @Veilkrand it is not true. I need to do something similar to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612435/how-to-convert-string-without-quotes-to-dictionary-in-python/52612645

Comment: @EricBellet check my answer

Comment: You can sequentially parse the string character by character, only splitting key value pairs when you hit a separator while not within an 'inner object'(this can be checked by tracking the number of open and close parenthesis). It's tedious, but it will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to process the string to add in the quotes before trying to evaluate:

```
import re
import ast

s = "{source: s3, aws_access_key_id: myaws, aws_secret_access_key: REDACTED_POSSIBLE_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, bucketName: bucket, region_name: eu-west-1, fileType: zip, typeIngestion: FULL, project: trackingcampaigns, functionalArea: client, filePaths: [s3Sensor/2018/], prefixFiles: [Tracking_Sent, Tracking_Bounces, Tracking_Opens, Tracking_Clicks, Tracking_SendJobs], prefixToTables: {Tracking_Bounces: MNG_TRACKING_EXTRACT_BOUNCES_3, Tracking_Sent: MNG_TRACKING_EXTRACT_SENT_3, Tracking_Clicks: MNG_TRACKING_EXTRACT_CLICKS_3, Tracking_Opens: MNG_TRACKING_EXTRACT_OPENS_3, Tracking_SendJobs: MNG_TRACKING_EXTRACT_SENDJOBS_3}, stagingPath: /zipFiles/}"

s = re.sub(r':\s?(?![{\[\s])([^,}]+)', r': "\1"', s) #Add quotes to dict values
s = re.sub(r'(\w+):', r'"\1":', s) #Add quotes to dict keys

def add_quotes_to_lists(match):
    return re.sub(r'([\s\[])([^\],]+)', r'\1"\2"', match.group(0))

s = re.sub(r'\[[^\]]+', add_quotes_to_lists, s) #Add quotes to list items

final = ast.literal_eval(s) #Evaluate the dictionary

print(final)
```

Not the prettiest solution, and I only have one example of input so I can't guarantee how robust this solution is, but it works for the sample provided.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is very easy to do in a robust way with just the built-in modules, so here's a solution that makes use of [PyParsing](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing). I took the example [jsonParser.py](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/master/examples/jsonParser.py) and modified it to recognize strings that don't use quote marks, and added a set literal for your `{myaws1, myaws2}` value.

```
import pyparsing as pp
from pyparsing import pyparsing_common as ppc

def make_keyword(kwd_str, kwd_value):
    return pp.Keyword(kwd_str).setParseAction(pp.replaceWith(kwd_value))
TRUE  = make_keyword("true", True)
FALSE = make_keyword("false", False)
NULL  = make_keyword("null", None)

LBRACK, RBRACK, LBRACE, RBRACE, COLON = map(pp.Suppress, "[]{}:")

jsonString = pp.OneOrMore(pp.CharsNotIn('{}[]:,')).setParseAction(lambda s, l, t: [t[0].strip()])
jsonNumber = ppc.number()

jsonObject = pp.Forward()
jsonValue = pp.Forward()
jsonElements = pp.delimitedList( jsonValue )
jsonArray = pp.Group(LBRACK + pp.Optional(jsonElements, []) + RBRACK)
jsonSet = pp.Group(LBRACE + pp.Optional(jsonElements, []) + RBRACE).setParseAction(lambda s,l,t: set(t[0]))
jsonValue << (jsonNumber | jsonString | pp.Group(jsonObject)  | jsonArray | jsonSet | TRUE | FALSE | NULL)
memberDef = pp.Group(jsonString + COLON + jsonValue)
jsonMembers = pp.delimitedList(memberDef)
jsonObject << pp.Dict(LBRACE + pp.Optional(jsonMembers) + RBRACE)

jsonComment = pp.cppStyleComment
jsonObject.ignore(jsonComment)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s ='{source: [s3, kinesis], aws_access_key_id: {myaws1, myaws2}, aws_secret_access_key: REDACTED_POSSIBLE_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, bucketName: bucket, region_name: eu-west-1, fileType: zip, typeIngestion: FULL, project: trackingcampaigns, functionalArea: client, filePaths: [s3Sensor/2018/], prefixFiles: [Tracking_Sent, Tracking_Bounces, Tracking_Opens, Tracking_Clicks, Tracking_SendJobs], prefixToTables: {Tracking_Bounces: MNG_TRACKING_EXTRACT_BOUNCES_3, Tracking_Sent: MNG_TRACKING_EXTRACT_SENT_3, Tracking_Clicks: MNG_TRACKING_EXTRACT_CLICKS_3, Tracking_Opens: MNG_TRACKING_EXTRACT_OPENS_3, Tracking_SendJobs: MNG_TRACKING_EXTRACT_SENDJOBS_3}, stagingPath: /zipFiles/}'

    results = jsonObject.parseString(s)
    print(results.asDict())
```

Result:

```
{'source': ['s3', 'kinesis'], 'aws_access_key_id': {'myaws1', 'myaws2'}, 'aws_secret_access_key': 'REDACTED_POSSIBLE_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', 'bucketName': 'bucket', 'region_name': 'eu-west-1', 'fileType': 'zip', 'typeIngestion': 'FULL', 'project': 'trackingcampaigns', 'functionalArea': 'client', 'filePaths': ['s3Sensor/2018/'], 'prefixFiles': ['Tracking_Sent', 'Tracking_Bounces', 'Tracking_Opens', 'Tracking_Clicks', 'Tracking_SendJobs'], 'prefixToTables': {'Tracking_Bounces': 'MNG_TRACKING_EXTRACT_BOUNCES_3', 'Tracking_Sent': 'MNG_TRACKING_EXTRACT_SENT_3', 'Tracking_Clicks': 'MNG_TRACKING_EXTRACT_CLICKS_3', 'Tracking_Opens': 'MNG_TRACKING_EXTRACT_OPENS_3', 'Tracking_SendJobs': 'MNG_TRACKING_EXTRACT_SENDJOBS_3'}, 'stagingPath': '/zipFiles/'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions to format the string before preparing it's `json` representation.

```
import re
json_string = {}
pattern = re.compile(r'(\w*):\s(\w*)')
matches = re.finditer(pattern, s)
for match in matches:
    json_string[match.group(1)] = match.group(2)
print(json_string)
```

Your string shows a pattern where the `key` `value` pair for your `json` string is separated by a `:` followed by a `whitespace`. `\w*` matches any no. of string characters(in addition to numbers) and `\s` helps you detect the whitespace.
`finditer` methods returns an iterable for you to loop through and grab the groups inside your pattern. You can read more about group ids [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.Pattern.groupindex)

Answer (score -3):

Not tested but you could do some string cleanup and split the keys and values into a dictionary:

```
s ='{source: s3, aws_access_key_id: myaws, aws_secret_access_key: REDACTED_POSSIBLE_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, bucketName: bucket, region_name: eu-west-1, fileType: zip, typeIngestion: FULL, project: trackingcampaigns, functionalArea: client, filePaths: [s3Sensor/2018/], prefixFiles: [Tracking_Sent, Tracking_Bounces, Tracking_Opens, Tracking_Clicks, Tracking_SendJobs], prefixToTables: {Tracking_Bounces: MNG_TRACKING_EXTRACT_BOUNCES_3, Tracking_Sent: MNG_TRACKING_EXTRACT_SENT_3, Tracking_Clicks: MNG_TRACKING_EXTRACT_CLICKS_3, Tracking_Opens: MNG_TRACKING_EXTRACT_OPENS_3, Tracking_SendJobs: MNG_TRACKING_EXTRACT_SENDJOBS_3}, stagingPath: /zipFiles/}'

s = s[1:-1]
data = {i.split(': ')[0]: i.split(': ')[1] for i in s.split(', ')}
```

Comment: This is the answer to the post that I shared with you, I had arrays and sub-dictionaries as values so that solution it does not work